# Getting active tab on button click and pass it to controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm currently working with MVC3 and Bootstrap.

I have a view with several Bootstrap tabs. Also I have a button [Create] that calls to Create() function in controller.

When clicking on [Create] button I need the following:

1.- Get the active tab id in order to pass it to the controller.

2.- Remain on the current (active) tab when the user has posted data and the page reloads

I know that i need to use Javascript to get the active tab and AJAX to pass the ID to the controller. I tried to mix them unsuccessfully in different ways. Actually I'm newbie in AJAX but i noticed that I'm missing to call the actions on button click event, but i don´t know how to codify it  :(

My JS:

```
$(function() { 
    var activeTab = null;
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown', function (e) {
      activeTab = e.target;
      //save the latest tab
      localStorage.setItem('lastTab', $(e.target).attr('id'));

      $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Create")',
                type: 'GET',
                data: postData,
                success: function(result) {

                }
            });

    });

      //go to the latest tab, if it exists:
      var lastTab = localStorage.getItem('lastTab');
      if (lastTab) {
        $('#'+lastTab).tab('show');
      }
});
```

[Create] button...

```
<button type="submit" class = "btn btn-success">
    <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i> Create
</button>
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you can do this, it just depends on what technologies/frameworks you want to use. If you want to stick with vanilla MVC, you can look at the [AjaxHelpers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493114%28v=vs.98%29.aspx). These offer markup helpers like `@Ajax.BeginForm(...)` and `@Ajax.ActionLink(...)` which automagically submit form data or invoke a controller action from a link via an AJAX call.

If you want more control over how AJAX calls are made, you can look at client side frameworks like [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) or [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/). I actually prefer Knockout as it allows you to easily adopt the MVVM design pattern in MVC. For example, here's a simple Knockout view model:

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.tabs = ko.observableArray([
        { id: 1, name: 'Tab 1' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Tab 2' },
        { id: 3, name: 'Tab 3' }
    ]);

    self.saveChanges = function () {

        // Here's where you can get the id of the selected tab
        // and make your ajax call

        var tab = $('.tab-content > .active').get(0);        
        alert('Hello from Tab ' + $(tab).attr('id'));
    };
}
```

And the markup:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-bind="foreach: tabs">
    <li data-bind="css: { 'active': $index() === 0 }">
        <a data-bind="attr: { href: '#' + $data.id }, text: $data.name" data-toggle="tab"></a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <!-- ko foreach: tabs -->
    <div class="tab-pane" data-bind="attr: { id: $data.id }, css: { 'active': $index() === 0 }">
        <p data-bind="text: $data.name + ' content...'"></p>

        <button class="btn" data-bind="click: $parent.saveChanges">Save</button>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

In this example, the view model determines which tabs to display and what actions can be invoked on the client. To see this actually working, refer to this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5qx29/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually Im using jQuery and Bootstrap on my MVC3 project. Your fiddle works like a charm and it is exactly what i'm looking for but seems to be quite complex for me. The snag is that i want to avoid using other libraries. I think I'm close to the solution but, as i said, I am newbie with jQuery and AJAX and I'm aware that my code is missing the onClick event on the button as well as the parameter at controller call.

Comment: There's no "disadvantage" per se sticking with jQuery, but I would still strongly recommend learning how to use the AjaxHelpers I linked to. Since I don't really use them, I haven't provided any examples.

Comment: Thanks @sellmeadog I'll follow your suggestion to learn about these helpers and I'll try to do it using them.